# MYSQL Select using Left Join, Count, Group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join

I have this query:

```
SELECT c.`id`, w.`qty`, COUNT(c.`id`) AS pieces, c.`location`
FROM `control` AS c
LEFT JOIN `warehouse` AS w ON w.`id` = c.`id`
WHERE c.`code` = '40'
GROUP BY c.`id`
```

I have these tables:

```
`control` c                                 `warehouse` w
+----+--------+------+----------+          +------+-------+
| id | pieces | code | location |          |  id  |  qty  |
+----+--------+------+----------+          +------+-------+
| 112|  112-1 |  40  |  london  |          |  112 |   3   |
| 112|  112-2 |  40  |  london  |          |  113 |   3   |
| 112|  112-3 |  40  |  london  |          |  114 |   1   |
| 113|  113-1 |  40  |  italy   |          |  115 |   1   |
| 113|  113-2 |  40  |  italy   |          +--------------+
| 113|  113-3 |  40  |  italy   |
| 114|  114-1 |  41  |  france  |
| 115|  115-1 |  41  |  france  |
| 112|  112-1 |  40  |  germany |
| 112|  112-2 |  40  |  germany |
| 112|  112-3 |  40  |  germany |
| 113|  112-1 |  40  |  russia  |
| 113|  112-2 |  40  |  russia  |
| 113|  112-3 |  40  |  russia  |
| 112|  112-1 |  40  |  poland  |
| 112|  112-2 |  40  |  poland  |
| 112|  112-3 |  40  |  poland  |
+-------------------------------+
```

Im getting this:

actual output

```
+-----+-----+--------+----------+
|  id | qty | pieces | location |
+-----+-----+--------+----------+
| 112 |  3  |    9   |  poland  |
| 113 |  3  |    6   |  russia  |
+-------------------------------+
```

I'm trying to get this result:

desired output

```
+-----+-----+--------+----------+
|  id | qty | pieces | location |
+-----+-----+--------+----------+
| 112 |  3  |    3   |  london  |
| 113 |  3  |    3   |  italy   |
| 112 |  3  |    3   |  germany |
| 113 |  3  |    3   |  russia  |
| 112 |  3  |    3   |  poland  |
+-------------------------------+
```

Is possible this result? maybe tweaking my query?
I tried without `GROUP BY` but in that case i just get 1 row totalizing `pieces`.

Comment: Please explain the logic of your Pieces column. Why you are counting id as pieces when you have such column in your table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate the different locations to different rows, you need to add that column to the `group by` clause:

```sql
SELECT c.`id`, w.`qty`, COUNT(c.`id`) AS pieces, c.`location`
FROM `control` AS c
LEFT JOIN `warehouse` AS w ON w.`id` = c.`id`
WHERE c.`code` = '40'
GROUP BY c.`id`, c.`location`
-- Here ---------^
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you just need to add `qty` and `location` to the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT c.`id`, w.`qty`, COUNT(*) AS pieces, c.`location`
FROM `control` AS c
LEFT JOIN `warehouse` AS w ON w.`id` = c.`id`
WHERE c.`code` = '40'
GROUP BY c.`id`, w.`qty`, c.`location`
```

Starting MySQL 5.7, it is mandatory to list all-non aggregated columns in the `group by` clause (unless you change default sql option `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`); most other databases also implement this constraint. I would recommend getting used to it...

Side notes:

- `COUNT(c.id)` is better written `COUNT(*)`, since `id` seems like a not nullable column
- generally spearking, you shoud avoid using backticks around table and column names unless when absolutly necessary.